# react-native: How to remove underline while typing text in TextInput Component on android device?

Tags: android, react-native

I want to remove underline while typing text inside the react native TextInput component on android device. Text underline removes as soon as press enter or spacebar. It's just showing until we type that word.

I have tried these options below:

- autoCorrect={false}
- spellCheck={false}
- underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
- underlineColorAndroid="rgba(0,0,0,0)"

```
<TextInput
  autoCorrect={false}
  spellCheck={false}
  underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
  placeholder="Username"
  style={styles.textInput}
/>
```

And my styles

```
 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  textInput: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontFamily: Platform.OS === "android" ? "Roboto" : "Avenir",
    color: colors.dark,
  }
 })
```

This is probably not a feature of keyboard app because in other app it is not showing the underline.

[image showing text input with underline text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywHDb.jpg)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's normal react-native behavior, but you can bypass it with:

```
keyboardType="visible-password"
```

Only caveat is that this disables multiline.

Comment: Yeah, its working somehow, thank you so much. Yes, it disables the multiline. What does visible-password actually means ?

Comment: It's a keyboard layout suitable for typing passwords + I guess visible means that the text in the input is not obscured.

Comment: Is there any solution to multiline input ? Can we mimic the multiline using styles ?